# Problem using the field 'from' in sql query

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT m.id, m.title, m.message, m.from, m.to2, m.to_viewed, m.from_viewed, m.created, u.username 
FROM tbl_messages m 
INNER JOIN tbl_users u 
ON m.from = u.id WHERE m.to2 = '1' && m.to_saved = '1'  && m.to_deleted = '0' 
ORDER BY m.created DESC
```

Having removed `m.from`, the query runs. It doesn't like this field name.
Is 'from' reserved?
Could someone suggest a fix?

Thanks

Comment: You should use backticks [`] with the keywords that are used as a column name or table name.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Syntax error due to using a reserved word as a table or column name in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23446377/syntax-error-due-to-using-a-reserved-word-as-a-table-or-column-name-in-mysql)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's one of the [reserved words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html). Use backticks to quote it:

```
m.`from`
```

Answer (score 3):

Wrap it with backticks, because it is mysql's reserved keyword

```
m.`from`
```

[Here is a full list of reserved words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/reserved-words.html)

Answer (score 1):

From is reserved, yes. You could try adding quotes around it. The easiest is to avoid using reserved words in queries.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is a reserved word. You should enclose from in back ticks like

```
m.`from`
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, "from" is reserved. In mysql, IIRC you can put it in either double quotes (") or backquotes (`) (but I also use postgresql, so I may be confusing the two systems).